# How to get array of string for particulate value in PHP?

Tags: php, magento

Here is my array and i get only name from that array so how can i get it

```
[
 {
  "name":"imgpsh_fullsize_anim_31.png",
  "type":"image\/png",
  "tmp_name":"\/tmp\/phpcaGk0O",
  "error":"0",
  "size":"34171",
  "file":"imgpsh_fullsize_anim_31.png",
  "cookie":
  {
   "name":"admin",
   "value":"s3jbpiubqq13tsrase0d4e6cma",
   "lifetime":"900000",
   "path":"\/nback",
  },
  "previewType":"image"
  }
 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is a JSON string you have in your hands so basically:

```
$arr = json_decode($str, true);
$name = $arr[0]["name"];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you call your array `$myArray` you would extract only the variable *name* like so:

```
$name = $myArray->name;
```

And if it's JSON:

```
$myJSONArray = json_decode($myArray);
$name = $myJSONArray[0]["name"];
```